# Set language description

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Lets say x is an element of (A union B) my understanding is that x is an element of A or x is an element of B. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

$A \cup B$ = $\{ x : x \in A \text { or } x \in B\}$

$
A \cap B = \{ x : x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\}$.

$A \triangle B = A - B \cup B - A = \{x : x \in A, x \not\in B\} \cup \{x : x \in B, x \not\in A\}$